# Reverse engineering C codes with GCC -march=i686

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, reverse-engineering

Here're my C codes:

```
int test(int x, int y){
    int val=4*x;
    if (y>0){
        if (x<y) val=x-y;
        else val=x^y;
    }
    else if (y<-2) val=x+y;
    return val;
}
```

And here're what I entered in the GCC command line:

```
gcc -O1 -S -march=i686 test.c
```

And here is the S file I got (only the calculation part):

```
pushl   %ebx
movl    8(%esp), %ecx
movl    12(%esp), %edx
testl   %edx, %edx
jle     L2
movl    %ecx, %eax
subl    %edx, %eax
movl    %edx, %ebx
xorl    %ecx, %ebx
cmpl    %edx, %ecx
cmovge  %ebx, %eax
jmp     L4

L2:
leal    0(,%ecx,4), %eax
addl    %edx, %ecx
cmpl    $-2, %edx
cmovl   %ecx, %eax

L4:
popl    %ebx
ret
```

My question is: can I get back exactly the same C codes using the S file above? I mean EXACTLY the same. For example can I determine the default value of `val` is `4*x` (line #2 of C codes)? Can I determine the test-expression of each `if` statement?

I really need your help. Thank you!!!

Comment: No.  There is no way to determine the variable names for example.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you can find out that the each registers corresponding to a variable:

- `%eax` - `var`
- `%ebx` - a contextual temporary variable
- `%ecx` - `x`
- `%edx` - `y`

If you mean 'exactly' for the identifiers, it is only possible when a special structure named 'symbol table'. (compiled with `-g` flag in GCC)

Anyway, you should know a code can be always optimized by the compiler. It means, in this case, your code is changed to another having same mathematical meaning. If your code is backward-translated, it should be like this.

```
int test(int x, int y) {
    int val;
    if (y > 0) {
        if (x < y)
            val = x - y;
        else
            val = x ^ y;
    } else {
        if (y < -2)
            val = x + y;
        else
            val = 4 * x;
    }
    return val;
}
```

If you want no optimization, use flag `-O0` instead of `-O1`.

Comment: :Thank you. Actually this is a practice problem on a book I'm reading. The solution on the book suggests that you really CAN use the assembly codes above to get the original C codes because GCC always follows some specific rules. For example, for the "if-else" statement in C, the compiler will consider "else" first. And that explains the "jle L2" on line #5 of the S file.

Comment: But even if this is true I still cannot backward-translate line 6-12 and line 14-17 because here the compiler is using i686 and seems to consider both situations at the same time...Anyone have any ideas about translation over these parts?

Comment: This is an optimization skill using conditional instructions. By doing this, there come less branches. You may know branches cause performance loss.

Comment: So you mean there is no way to translate those parts?

Comment: I think you can, however. Yes. Try compiling your code and mine, and then the last `if` statement replaced by `if (y >= -2) val = 4 * x; else val = x + y;`. There comes a small but significant footprint of GCC. Maybe it's possible if you are fully skilled.

Comment: When I revised my codes I did notice some significant changes of the resulting assembly codes, but somehow they are different with the example codes from my book. In the book gcc stores the result of "else" statement in %eax, but in my codes %eax stores the result of the "if" statement. So maybe there's really no way to translate...